# Mvc dll missing from Msbuild web deploy package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild-4.0

I create a web deploy package from Visual Studio 2010, Build Deployment Package.

The items to deploy is set to "All files in this project".

I install it on the server using Web deploy, via Import Application in IIS Manager.

It installs, but when I Browse the website I get the yellow screen of death, Configuration Error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc".

If I drill right down into the .zip file created by the deployment package, the System.Web.Mvc.dll is not in there.

Is the correct procedure to get the System.Web.Mvc.dll into my deployment package, or am I supposed to install Mvc separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Darin. I found another answer... if I set Copy Local to true on the Mvc references then it will include those dlls in my web deploy package.

- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Routing
- System.Web.Abstractions

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

-Matt

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to install ASP.NET MVC separately on the server and this assembly will be deployed in the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

How to bin deploy MVC3  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx